# Python3 проблема с threading и asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, asyncio

Очень не хочу лезть в потоково-асинхронную кашу, но я уже в ней.

Написал скрипт, который делает бэкапы сервера и отправляет отчеты о них.
Помимо этого, он отчитывается о статусе сервера и статусе бэкапов в телеграм боте через библиотеку `aiogram`.

То-есть, разделите мой код на 2 части:

- Бекапер
- Бот

#### Проблема:

Я пытаюсь запустить процесс создания бэкапов в отдельном потоке.
Из этого же потока я хочу отправлять сообщения от имени бота *подписчикам*.

**Создание потока под бэкапы**

```
Thread(target=BackUp().start).start()
```

**Функция рассылки подписчикам**

```
async def notify_staff(msg: str, kind='Info', notification=True) -> None:
    staff = [x for x in Session().query(Staff)]
    message = '*\\[{kind}\\]*\n{msg}'.format(kind=markdown_decoration.quote(kind),
                                           msg=markdown_decoration.quote(msg))
    for obj in staff:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=obj.chat_id, text=message, parse_mode='MarkdownV2',
                               disable_notification=not notification)
        sleep(0.4)
```

И суть проблемы в том, что **вызов**

```
class BackUp:
    def start(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        while True:
            ...
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(notify_staff(msg='Backup done\nStored paths:\n{paths}'.format(
                        paths='\n'.join([x['path'] for x in stored])
                    ), notification=False), loop)
            ...
```

выполняется бесконечно. *(Дебаг помог)*
Точнее, он, похоже, просто бесконечно ничего не делает.

Была попытка отправить в другой поток непосредственно бота и все заработало... за исключением бота, который уже не откликался на команды.

Не понимаю почему не отрабатывает `run_coroutine_threadsafe()`

Comment: потому что луп новый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что ты мешаешь код в разных тредах. Тред бакупа не должен знать ничего о телеграмме и тем более не должен создавать новый луп. Используй [concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
backup_future = loop.run_in_executor(executor, BackUp().start)
wait_complete_task = loop.create_task(on_backup_done(backup_future))
```

где в on_backup_done описывается взаимодействеие с телеграмом, запущенном в основном лупе и выполняется оно в основном треде.

```
async def on_backup_done(backup_future):
    result = await backup_future
    await notify_staff(msg='Backup done....)
```

Comment: Ругается на `loop.create_task(on_backup_done, backup_future)`. Что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Согласен с питоном - `backup_future` unexpected. Но вашу идею я тоже понял, но чет щас не особо варю что придумать

Comment: @icYFTL ну мржет скобок не хватает где. не проверял. суть в том что задача в тред пуле передается таску, который её дождется и выдаст сообщение